# Looping through UIImageViews in UIView - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiimageview, swift2

I've been trying to do something in Swift that is very similar to the below code sample (Objective C). Is anyone able to provide a Swift implementation of the function shown below or something similar?

```
- (UIImageView *) getSectorByValue:(int)value {
UIImageView *res;
NSArray *views = [container subviews];
for (UIImageView *im in views) {
    if (im.tag == value)
        res = im;
}
return res;
```

}

Answer (score 1):

This is a similar implementation in Swift:

```
func getSectorByValue(value: Int) -> UIImageView? {
    for subView in container.subviews {
        if subView.tag == value {
            return subView as? UIImageView
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work.

```
func getSectorByValue(value: Int) -> UIImageView? {
    let views = container.subviews() 
    if let i = views.indexOf({$0.tag == value}) {
        return views[i] as? UIImageView
    }
    return nil
}
```

Comment: It's not happy about returning UIView as UIImageView.

Answer (score 0):

Looping though the subviews manually is needlessly complex.

There is a `UIView` method `viewWithTag` that fetches the desired view with 1 line of code:

```
func getSectorByValue(value: Int) -> UIImageView? 
{
    return container.viewWithTag(value) as? UIImageView
}
```

Comment: Why the down-vote? This is a cleaner, more efficient solution to the actual problem than approach the OP was using.

Comment: I feel like in light of this answer, other answers should get downvoted.

Comment: The question is an example of an [**XY problem**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)